# Markdown export for Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, markdown

We all love Markdown, right? So why can't I get my careers profile exported as a markdown file instead of a fixed-format PDF with some information present, and some missing? I use Careers as my *only* up-to-date resume, and sometimes I want to create a nice-looking document from my profile.

Can we have a markdown export of the full careers profile?

Comment: Sorry, wrong meta. I assumed, since it was Stack Overflow careers, that meta stack overflow was the right place to ask!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pushed this; you can now click the 'create markdown' link in the sidebar when you view your profile:

[image: 'create markdown']

This brings you to the preview page - this is markdown rendered with a custom stylesheet. In contrast to PDF export you can't pick and choose the sections to render here - it's much easier to edit markdown after all so didn't seem necessary.

Press [image: 'Export to Markdown'] to download the markdown.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much!

Comment: And where is this button now? I don't see it